# Sharepoint 2013 Access App - Request Not Completed - Access Denied

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, sharepoint-2013, access-denied, ms-access-2013

In a project context:  SQL Server 2012, SP 2013 (build version:  15.0.4481.1005)

I added Access Apps downloaded from the SharePoint Store to a SharePoint sub-site but I keep on having this issue: "Request Not Completed - You do not have permission to view the records. To obtain permission, contact your site administrator." while trying to open them.

This is happening whatever the Access App is: I tried "Recruiting Helper" and "Orders and Products". For information, they are working correctly when I'm adding them to the SharePoint root site!

Do you have any idea where this can come from?

```
ResponseTimeUsageProvider: Writing log usage succeeded for Operation: ExecuteScalar. System: SQLCallFromADS. DatabaseName: ... . StartTime: 11/07/2013 11:01:51. EndTime: 11/07/2013 11:01:51. Notes: UlsCorrelationID: f942549c-a3cf-5096-f9b9-504710cde05f; CommandText: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.fulltext_catalogs;

Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070005

SPRequest.GetUsersDataAsSafeArray: UserPrincipalName=, AppPrincipalName=... ,bstrUrl=... ,dwUsersScope=5 ,dwUserCollectionFlags=0 ,bstrValue= ,dwValue=1073741823

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)), StackTrace:   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser.InitMember()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser..ctor(SPWeb web, SPSecurableObject scope, String strIdentifier, Object[,] arrUsersData, UInt32 index, Int32 iByParamId, String strByParamSID, String strByParamEmail, SPUserCollectionType userCollectionType, SPUserCollectionFlags ucf, Boolean isSiteAuditor)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.GetByIDNoThrow(Int32 id)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.get_SystemAccount()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.Host.MossHostHelperMethods.RunAsSiteSystemAccount(SafeSPWeb web, Action`1 method)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.MossHost.MossApplicationPeer.set_FullTextEnabled(Nullable`1 value)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.OM.Application.get_FullTextEnabled()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.Data.SqlDataProvider.GetData(Application application, CurrentUserBase user, AccessObjectSchema objectSchema, IEnumerable`1 fields, String restriction, FilterInfoEx filter, String sortExpression, IDictionary`2 queryParameters, Int32 startRow, Int32 endRow, Boolean retrieveExactRowCount, Int32& totalRowCount)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.DataServer.CachedResultSet.RetrieveData(Int32 startRow, Int32 endRow)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.DataServer.WebService.AccessServiceSoap.OpenResultSetInternal(CommandParameter parameter, FieldList fields, String restriction, KeyValuePair[] queryParameters, String sortExpression, FilterInfo filter, String moniker, Int32 startRowIndex, Int32 maximumRows, Boolean lockSession, Boolean autoResync, Boolean retrieveExactRowCount, DataTable& tempTable, Int32& tempTotalRowCount)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.DataServer.WebService.AccessServiceSoap.c__DisplayClassbe.b__bb()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.DataServer.WebService.AccessServiceSoap.ExecuteDataServerOperation(CommandParameter parameter, String protocolVersion, String moniker, AccessDataServerOperation op, WebMethodType webMethodType, PCID pcidTimeAvg, PCID pcidTimeAvgBase, Guid userCookieId, Boolean isApplicationDesignOperation, Boolean isDatabaseProviderOperation, String container)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.DataServer.WebService.AccessServiceSoap.OpenResultSet(CommandParameter parameter, FieldList fields, String container, String restriction, KeyValuePair[] queryParameters, String sortExpression, FilterInfo filter, String source, Int32 startRowIndex, Int32 maximumRows, Boolean autoResync, Boolean retrieveExactRowCount, String& tableXml, Int32& totalRowCount, Guid userCookieId)    
 at SyncInvokeOpenResultSet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)    
 at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)    
 at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.InnerTryReceiveCompletedCallback(IAsyncResult result)    
 at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)    
 at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)    
 at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)    
 at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)    
 at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.Enqueue(QueueItemType item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.CompleteParseAndEnqueue(IAsyncResult result)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.HandleParseIncomingMessage(IAsyncResult result)    
 at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.SyncContinue(IAsyncResult result)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor replyChannelAcceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1.ProcessHttpContextAsync()    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.BeginHttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action acceptorCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()    
 at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()    
 at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)    
 at System.ServiceModel.AspNetPartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback, Object state)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(Object state)    
 at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)    
 at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)    
 at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)

 Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070005

 SPRequest.GetUsersDataAsSafeArray: UserPrincipalName=, AppPrincipalName= ,bstrUrl=... ,dwUsersScope=5 ,dwUserCollectionFlags=0 ,bstrValue= ,dwValue=1073741823

 System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)), StackTrace:   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser.InitMember()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser..ctor(SPWeb web, SPSecurableObject scope, String strIdentifier, Object[,] arrUsersData, UInt32 index, Int32 iByParamId, String strByParamSID, String strByParamEmail, SPUserCollectionType userCollectionType, SPUserCollectionFlags ucf, Boolean isSiteAuditor)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.GetByIDNoThrow(Int32 id)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.get_SystemAccount()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.Host.MossHostHelperMethods.c__DisplayClass2.b__0()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.c__DisplayClass5.b__3()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.Host.MossHostHelperMethods.RunAsSiteSystemAccount(SafeSPWeb web, Action`1 method)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.MossHost.MossApplicationPeer.set_FullTextEnabled(Nullable`1 value)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.OM.Application.get_FullTextEnabled()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.Data.SqlDataProvider.GetData(Application application, CurrentUserBase user, AccessObjectSchema objectSchema, IEnumerable`1 fields, String restriction, FilterInfoEx filter, String sortExpression, IDictionary`2 queryParameters, Int32 startRow, Int32 endRow, Boolean retrieveExactRowCount, Int32& totalRowCount)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.DataServer.CachedResultSet.RetrieveData(Int32 startRow, Int32 endRow)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.DataServer.WebService.AccessServiceSoap.OpenResultSetInternal(CommandParameter parameter, FieldList fields, String restriction, KeyValuePair[] queryParameters, String sortExpression, FilterInfo filter, String moniker, Int32 startRowIndex, Int32 maximumRows, Boolean lockSession, Boolean autoResync, Boolean retrieveExactRowCount, DataTable& tempTable, Int32& tempTotalRowCount)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.DataServer.WebService.AccessServiceSoap.c__DisplayClassbe.b__bb()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.DataServer.WebService.AccessServiceSoap.ExecuteDataServerOperation(CommandParameter parameter, String protocolVersion, String moniker, AccessDataServerOperation op, WebMethodType webMethodType, PCID pcidTimeAvg, PCID pcidTimeAvgBase, Guid userCookieId, Boolean isApplicationDesignOperation, Boolean isDatabaseProviderOperation, String container)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.DataServer.WebService.AccessServiceSoap.OpenResultSet(CommandParameter parameter, FieldList fields, String container, String restriction, KeyValuePair[] queryParameters, String sortExpression, FilterInfo filter, String source, Int32 startRowIndex, Int32 maximumRows, Boolean autoResync, Boolean retrieveExactRowCount, String& tableXml, Int32& totalRowCount, Guid userCookieId)    
 at SyncInvokeOpenResultSet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)    
 at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)    
 at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.InnerTryReceiveCompletedCallback(IAsyncResult result)    
 at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)    
 at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)    
 at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)    
 at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)    
 at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.Enqueue(QueueItemType item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.CompleteParseAndEnqueue(IAsyncResult result)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.HandleParseIncomingMessage(IAsyncResult result)    
 at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.SyncContinue(IAsyncResult result)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor replyChannelAcceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1.ProcessHttpContextAsync()    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.BeginHttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action acceptorCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()    
 at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()    
 at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)    
 at System.ServiceModel.AspNetPartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback, Object state)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(Object state)    
 at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)    
 at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)    
 at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)

 SqlDataProvider.GetData: Exception thrown: {System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetUsersDataAsSafeArray(String bstrUrl, UInt32 dwUsersScope, UInt32 dwUserCollectionFlags, String bstrValue, UInt32 dwValue, UInt32& pdwColCount, UInt32& pdwRowCount, Object& pvarDataSet)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser.InitMember()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser..ctor(SPWeb web, SPSecurableObject scope, String strIdentifier, Object[,] arrUsersData, UInt32 index, Int32 iByParamId, String strByParamSID, String strByParamEmail, SPUserCollectionType userCollectionType, SPUserCollectionFlags ucf, Boolean isSiteAuditor)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserCollection.GetByIDNoThrow(Int32 id)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.get_SystemAccount()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.Host.MossHostHelperMethods.c__DisplayClass2.b__0()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.c__DisplayClass5.b__3()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.Host.MossHostHelperMethods.RunAsSiteSystemAccount(SafeSPWeb web, Action`1 method)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.MossHost.MossApplicationPeer.set_FullTextEnabled(Nullable`1 value)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.OM.Application.get_FullTextEnabled()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Access.Services.Data.SqlDataProvider.GetData(Application application, CurrentUserBase user, AccessObjectSchema objectSchema, IEnumerable`1 fields, String restriction, FilterInfoEx filter, String sortExpression, IDictionary`2 queryParameters, Int32 startRow, Int32 endRow, Boolean retrieveExactRowCount, Int32& totalRowCount)}

 ResponseTimeUsageProvider: Writing log usage succeeded for Operation: GetData:ExecuteReader. System: SQLCallFromADS. DatabaseName: .... StartTime: 11/07/2013 11:01:51. EndTime: 11/07/2013 11:01:51. Notes: UlsCorrelationID: f942549c-a3cf-5096-f9b9-504710cde05f;
```

Comment: Did you just decide to download an access app or have you also gone through the setup of the Access Services in SharePoint 2013?
I would assume that this is on-prem.

Comment: Yes, it is SharePoint on-premise. But we missed the GrantAccessToProcessIdentity step during the setup of Access servicess:
$w = Get-SPWebApplication [WebAppUrl]
$w.GrantAccessToProcessIdentity("spaccessuser)
$w.Update()

Problem solved now. Thanks!